# Quit vim externally without kill command

Tags: vim

I was booted from an ssh session while in a vim session. Apparently, the vim session is still open, but I cannot seem to access it. Also, when I try to kill it, I don't have permission. I know the pid's of the vim sessions but I can't find the right command to either re-enter those sessions or quit them.

Comment: `kill` is really the only tool you have, and it should work.  It's possible you'll need to do `kill -9` or switch user to root to kill it.

Comment: so, I type `pidof vim`, and it gives me a list of the id's e.g. `1090`. I then type `kill 1090` - is that correct?

Comment: that should work, if not try `kill -9 1090`

Comment: yeah, operation not permitted apparently :( thanks though

Comment: Is there a way to re-enter old sessions?

Comment: Not that I know of.  One last thing to try -- some systems let you borrow root privs  with sudo. Try  `sudo kill -9 1090` -- it might prompt you for your password or for root's password, or tell you you can't do it.  Worth a try though.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I don't have sudo perms either... I contacted the cluster's support so hopefully they have a solution! Thanks for your help!

Comment: For your next session, consider using screen or tmux on the server.

Comment: You might be able to use a program like [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) which takes existing running program and attachs it to a new terminal. May also want to see this post: [How do I attach a terminal to a detached process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-do-i-attach-a-terminal-to-a-detached-process). I agree with others it might be best to use screen or tmux in the future